# Project linking for Visual Studio Setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, localization, setup-project, setup-deployment

Environment:
Visual Studio Ultimate 2010
.NET 4.0
Windows XP, Vista and 7

We have a Visual Studio Setup project with 30 to 40 projects in it.

Now we need the setup in two languages.

The only property I would like to change is the "Localization"

Is it possible to share the project and only change the Localization project while generating the two deployment packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this thread for localizing an MSI:
[Setup.exe calling msi based on Regional setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351530/setup-exe-calling-msi-based-on-regional-setting/7354180#7354180)

I don't see how you could share a setup project in order to generate multiple packages. I think you need two separate setup projects, one for each language.